# Permissions error for delegated service account login for YouTube brand account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am trying to get access to my brand account's YouTube reporting data programmatically via delegated service account credentials and having trouble, figuring out how to do it.

So far, I've been successfully able to run delegated API requests **without** `onBehalfOfContentOwner` being supplied (i.e. returns correct data for that account), so I know that service account delegation is viable and configured properly. But when trying to get data for the content owner with `onBehalfOfContentOwner` that the delegation account has access to, I get the error below.

I have also verified that my delegation email address does indeed have access to query the brand account's data programmatically as have been able to successfully make requests to the content owner's / brand account's data with the "Try it yourself" section of the YouTube documents and in the Oauth playground. Is there a way to build a token with respect to the desired brand account? Or something else I am missing?

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',  
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly'
]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_cred, 
    scopes=SCOPES,
    subject='myemail@mycompany.com'
)

credentials.refresh(
    google.auth.transport.requests.Request())

youtube_reporting = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'youtubereporting', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

print(youtube_reporting.reportTypes().list(onBehalfOfContentOwner='mycontentownerid').execute())
```

> ```
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/reportTypes?onBehalfOfContentOwner=mycontentownerid&alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller does not have permission">
> ```

Comment: **authenticatedUserNotChannel :** For this request the authenticated user must resolve to a channel, but does not. If your request is authenticated and uses the **onBehalfOfContentOwner** delegation parameter, then you should also set the **onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel** parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this API call doesn't seem to accept that keyword arg

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid Permission Denied when setting up Schedule Query with a Service Account, follow below steps:**

1. The [**roles/bigquery.admin**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions) includes all IAM Permissions needed to schedule or modify a query. i.e. service account should have these permissions.
2. To create or update scheduled queries run by a service account, the user who is modifying must have access to the service account itself, by having the [Service Account user role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#user-role). This role can be assigned at the project level or Service account level. i.e. the user should have this permission

**NOTE:** When programmatically creating a scheduled query, the service account can sometimes be the user that is calling the SA. In this case, 1 of 3 things can be done:

**A.**  Grant the service account the Service Account User role to have access to itself

**B.**  Remove service_account_name from the request

**C.**  Use different credentials

**3. If these permissions are all assigned, and there is still a permission denied error, there may be an organization policy being enforced, check below steps :**

**a.**  The “**Disable Cross-Project Service Account Usage**” policy is enforced on a project level by default.You can go to IAM & Admin —> Organization Policies —> Search for Service Account.

**b.** Each service account is located in a project. You can go to IAM & Admin —> Service Accounts —> search for the service account to see if it is located in a certain project

**c.** [To use a service account cross-project](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#impersonation), you must disable the policy in the projects where the service accounts belong:

```
$ gcloud resource-manager org-policies disable-enforce 
iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage --project=[PROJECT-ID]
```

**d.**  To disable this policy, the user will need to be added as an [Organization Policy Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints#add-org-policy-admin). Only the Org Admin can grant someone this role.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to write a response, but this was about the YouTube api not setting up scheduled queries in BQ. I'm trying to get the data with python directly and not via BQ :)